# GetProcAddress fails even when name is correctly mangled

Tags: visual-c++, name-mangling, getprocaddress

I have the following code in a .dll:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall GetOptionID(unsigned long num)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is compiled on Visual C++ 2010, so I also have a .def file containing `GetOptionID`. I can see that the function is exported, and mangled as `_GetOptionID@4`, using dumpbin /exports:

```
File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for MyLibrary.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    53D269CB time date stamp Fri Jul 25 15:29:31 2014
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
          13 number of functions
          13 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 0006F030 CmdOne = _CmdOne@16
          2    1 0006F510 CmdUnimpl = _CmdUnimpl@16
          3    2 0006EBB0 DefineThing = _DefineThing@32
          4    3 0006E0C0 GetOptionID = _GetOptionID@4
```

In a separate executable, I attempt to check for the presence of `GetOptionID`:

```
HINSTANCE hinst = LoadLibraryEx(file_name, NULL, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES);
if(!hinst)
    return FALSE;

FARPROC_IDI lp = (FARPROC_IDI) GetProcAddress(hinst, "_GetOptionID@4");
auto e = GetLastError();
```

Running through this code in the debugger, I can see that:

- `LoadLibraryEx` succeeds - I have a valid-looking `hinst`
- `GetProcAddress` fails - `lp` is `0x00000000`
- `GetLastError` returns 127

I can see the function has been exported, and I can see its name matches the entry point I'm looking for. How come `GetProcAddress` is failing?

Comment: You are reading the output of dumpbin incorrectly. The exported name is the one on the left hand side of the equal sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, solved it myself. Defining the function in the .def file causes its name to be completely unmangled, meaning the correct target for `GetProcAddress` was simply `GetOptionID`.

However, since I have other .dlls that undergo the same check and really are `_GetOptionID@4`,  the actual solution was to remove GetOptionID from the .def file.